# Converting a website url into image in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I want to convert a website into an image file.
Is there any method in .NET library or any other method to do this?(As WebsiteToImage method in C#)

Answer (score 0):

You could the [WriteableBitmap.Render()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method, it allows you render a control to an image.

Of course you have to load the website into a control for that.